# What are the Parameters for in: Python, ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA?

Tags: python, windows, function, parameters, ctypes

What do the `20`, `0` and `3` mean in the Python function:

```
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER=20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,'imgpath', 3)
```

I'm quite new and haven't found any useful information. 
Also, can I define how the Wallpaper behaves, like stretch or tile or center?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Have you found how to stretch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SystemParametersInfoA` function is a direct Windows interface.  It is a `C` interface that in this case we are calling from Python.  But it is structured the way it is because it was designed to be called from `C`.  The interface can do a variety of things, and that variety is controlled by the integer value of the first parameter.  In this case, the value is:

```
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
```

The `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` name is used because this is how it will be referenced in all of the Windows Documentation. The `SystemParametersInfoA` function takes four parameters, the purpose of the last three vary depending on the function.  In this case the `0` is unused.  The purpose of the `imgpath` is self evident, but it does need to be a full path.  Finally, the `3` is two bit flags:

```
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01
SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02
```

This ([Source](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/cssetdesktopwallpaper-2107409c)) also has details on sizing the wallpaper.

Comment: Also, the image path needs to be fully qualified.

Comment: What is the parameter to set the image full screen?