# How to align new wallpaper using Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, mode, wallpaper, stretch

After changing the background correctly with the famous `ctypes`

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, fullpathofimage, 0)
```

the image was not fitting correctly in the screen, as Windows has 'Tile' as default wallpaper fit. Part of the image outgrew the screen.

¿Is there any way to change the wallpaper fit mode? (Center, Span, Fit, Stretch, etc)
After changing the fit mode of the computer, each new change of wallpaper would respect the new fit mode. So it must be a system parameter, but i dont know where to edit.

In this answer, [What are the Parameters for in: Python, ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474073/what-are-the-parameters-for-in-python-ctypes-windll-user32-systemparametersinf), someone replyed with https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/cssetdesktopwallpaper-2107409c, but now its down and i can't find anything.

Thank you ind advance.

Comment: Here's an [archive](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/OneCodeTeam/Set%20the%20desktop%20wallpaper%20(CSSetDesktopWallpaper)/) of the MSDN page you linked to.

Comment: @MattDMo apreciated. i will try to dig into the solution myself, but if someone has figured it out, i would be also grateful.

Comment: I know nothing about the weird and f---ed up world of Windows system internals (other than it's weird and f---ed up), otherwise I'd make an answer. I do have strong Google-fu, though, which is how I found that archive :)

Comment: @MattDMo i ended making the wallpaper smaller, so it is never shrunk and always full displayed.

Comment: I faced same task and I have not figured out any method besides changing registry keys in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\Desktop" with the use of winreg package in Python.